# Java - Out of Memory exception for array match

Tags: java, arrays, performance, comparison, out-of-memory

I am trying to match two huge text files (2GB size) using hash and arrays. Hash match is working since it just a string match between two files but array match is used when there are differences in two files and print not matching records. Out of Memory problem is occurred during array match. Please let me know an approach which will be more performance efficient when comparing huge text files and print non matching records.

Given below is the code and error.

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
```

**Java code:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.security.DigestInputStream;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

public class CompareTwoFiles {
    static int count1 = 0 ;
    static int count2 = 0 ;

    static String arrayLines1[] = new String[countLines("\\Files_Comparison\\File123.txt")];
    static String arrayLines2[] = new String[countLines("\\Files_Comparison\\File124.txt")];

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable{  
        long lStartTime = new Date().getTime();
        System.out.println("File1 count=" + countLines("\\Files_Comparison\\File123.txt"));
        System.out.println("File2 count=" + countLines("\\Files_Comparison\\File124.txt"));
        String checksum_1 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(new FileInputStream("\\Files_Comparison\\File123.txt"));
        String checksum_2 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(new FileInputStream("\\Files_Comparison\\File124.txt"));
        System.out.println(checksum_1);
        System.out.println(checksum_2);
        if (checksum_1.equals(checksum_2)) {
            System.out.println("File Comparison Process Completed");
            System.out.println("Both files are same");
        }
        else 
        {
        findDifference("\\Files_Comparison\\File123.txt","\\Files_Comparison\\File124.txt");
        displayRecords();
        System.out.println("File Comparison Process Completed");
        }
        long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();
        long difference = lEndTime - lStartTime; 
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(difference),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(difference) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(difference)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(difference) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(difference)));
        System.out.println(hms);
    }

    public static int countLines(String File){

        int lineCount = 0;
        try {
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(File));
           while ((br.readLine()) != null) {
               lineCount++;
           }

       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
           return lineCount;
    }

    public static void findDifference(String File1, String File2){
        String contents1 = null;  
        String contents2 = null; 
        try  
        {  
            FileReader file1 = new FileReader(File1);  
            FileReader file2 = new FileReader(File2);
            BufferedReader buf1 = new BufferedReader(file1); 
            BufferedReader buf2 = new BufferedReader(file2);

           while ((contents1 = buf1.readLine()) != null)  
            {  
               arrayLines1[count1] = contents1 ;
               count1++;
            }  

           while ((contents2 = buf2.readLine()) != null)  
            {  
               arrayLines2[count2] = contents2 ;
               count2++;
            }
       }catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
}





    public static void displayRecords() { 

        for (int i = 0 ; i < arrayLines1.length && i < arrayLines2.length; i++) 
        {    
            String a = arrayLines1[i];  
            String b = arrayLines2[i];  

            if(!a.contains(b)) {  
                   System.out.println(a);  
            }  
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of comparison are you wanting?  I see you're using a checksum of matching exactness, which is a good start, but what outcome do you want if the files differ?

Comment: I just want to print the non matching records in File1 which I am doing in displayRecords() method. Code is failing when I try to compare huge text files

Comment: What do you consider non-matching?  For example, if you have two lines which contain the same text but the first is at line 2 of file 1 and the second is at line 10 of file 2, are the considered a match?

Comment: Yes exactly, it is considered as match. Non match - a row which is not available or mismatch between two delimited text files.